# Uber RideRequestButtonCallback doesn't get called. - Android

Tags: android, callback, uber-api

I'm using the Uber RideRequestButton in my Android App. What I'm trying to do is load ride information for a specific product_id (UberGO) and then the button (which is currently View.GONE) to View.VISIBLE and then hide the progress bar.

All works just fine when the product_id is available. On callback, it calls `onRideInformationLoaded()` properly. The problem is when the product ID is not available. Then none of the methods in the callback get called. Why is that so? I still want to show the button even if the estimates are not available. Shouldn't it call one of the error methods?

Here is my code:

```
RideParameters.Builder rpBuilder = new RideParameters.Builder()
            .setProductId("83941b0d-4be1-4979-a9c0-f0af5ee2b89b")
            .setDropoffLocation(latitude, longitude, dropOffName, dropOffAddress)
            .setPickupToMyLocation();
    requestButton.setRideParameters(rpBuilder.build());
    cabDialog.addView(requestButton);
    requestButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    requestButton.setSession(new ServerTokenSession(configuration));
    requestButton.setCallback(new RideRequestButtonCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onRideInformationLoaded() {
            Log.i("Ride Info Loaded", "This method is being called.");
            requestButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pbLoadingUber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ApiError apiError) {
            requestButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pbLoadingUber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.w("Failed to Get Estimates", apiError.getClientErrors().get(0).getTitle());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.w("Failed to Get Estimates", throwable);
            requestButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pbLoadingUber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    requestButton.loadRideInformation();
```

**What is the issue?**

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce your problem. If you look at the latest Android Git version you will get the following error if product id does not exist:

[image]

The method where this is trapped is :

```
@Override
public void onError(ApiError apiError) {
    Toast.makeText(this, apiError.getClientErrors().get(0).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Implement your "activity" with : RideRequestButtonCallback and then @Override 3 interface methods.

So your code should looks like:

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RideRequestButtonCallback {
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
            .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
            .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setServerToken(SERVER_TOKEN)
            .build();
ServerTokenSession session = new ServerTokenSession(configuration);

RideParameters.Builder rpBuilder = new RideParameters.Builder()
        .setProductId("83941b0d-4be1-4979-a9c0-f0af5ee2b89b")
        .setDropoffLocation(latitude, longitude, dropOffName, dropOffAddress)
        .setPickupToMyLocation();
requestButton.setRideParameters(rpBuilder.build());
requestButton.setSession(session);
requestButton.setCallback(this);
cabDialog.addView(requestButton);
requestButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

@Override
public void onRideInformationLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Estimates have been refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onError(ApiError apiError) {
    Toast.makeText(this, apiError.getClientErrors().get(0).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
    Log.e("SampleActivity", "Error obtaining Metadata", throwable);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: I'm using it in a DialogFragment

Comment: Either way - we don't see any problem with the SDK - you will need to check your code.

Comment: So I implemented the methods in Dialog fragment and none of them are getting called. The Dialog Fragment now implements onRideRequestCallback and the three methods are the same. Will post code in a while. And I will try Toast instead of Log.i